# Should I do Japa to Ganesh first before any God?

Tags: mantras, ganesha, japa

I know Ganesh should be worshipped first before anyone during puja, but i have heard this about auspicious activities as well. So i am curious if I should also do this before Japa?

Comment: If your Guru advised you to do you should if not you can avoid .. but it's better to do Ganesha japa before any other japa.

Comment: @Rickross what’s the Mantra of Ganesh, ppl can chant without any initiation ? Or chanting slokas like “Vakratubda Mahakaya” is also permitted?

Comment: Yes,chanting that sloka is fine